# (Game Maker Studio)How to make an alarm that starts & loops in the step event?

Tags: game-maker

I'm making an enemy object where the enemy will go on a specific path to patrol.Then he will stop at a certain point to look around for the player.

I planned to make him change his sprite direction every 2 seconds(Enemies vision's for another day)but i seems to stuck here.I want the alarm to start as soon as he stops in the middle of the path,but i don't know how to activate the alarm in the step event.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, setting an alarm is just about giving `Alarm[0]` a value it needs to count down.
But in the Step Event, it would reset the value constantly. So it needs a statement where it only goes through setting the alarm once.

What I use is a switch statement with a new variable for each behavior it does. which I prefer to call them 'states'.

For example, in the Create event, you'll define a state. and write down the meaning next to it.

```
state = 0; //0 = walking, 1 = running.
```

It's also fine to use Enums for this once you're familiar with it. But I prefer ints to get started.

Then, in the Step Event:

```
switch (state)
{
   case 0: //walking
   {
      //walks around.
      break;
   }
   case 1:
   {
      //looks around
      break;
   }
}
```

Then, for example in the Alarm[0] event (Which triggers once the alarm reaches 0):

```
switch (state)
{
   case 0: //walking
   {
      alarm[0] = 2; //example of new value
      state = 1;
      break;
   }
   case 1:
   {
      alarm[0] = 2; //example of new value
      state = 2;
      break;
   }
}
```

Personally, I prefer custom variables to define counters and timers, as you can write these out in the step event completely, which I could try to explain later.

Hope it helps you out.

Answer (score -1):

Yes; using a custom counter was the way to go. I looked it up, and made my own counter.

Create:

```
sprar[0] = sprscout;
sprar[1] = sprscout_up;
sprar[2] = sprscout_down;

spcounter = 0;
```

Step:

```
 switch(state){ 
     case 0: spd = 0; 
     counter += 1; 
     if(counter >= room_speed*3){   
        spcounter ++; 
        sprite_index = sprar[spcounter];
     } break;
}
```

The sprite changes to up after 3 seconds, and then down immediately. The error occurs right after the sprite changes into the last sprite of the array:

> FATAL ERROR in action number 1 of  Step Event0 for object obj_EBase:
>   Push :: Execution Error - Variable Index [0,3] out of range [1,3] -
>   -1.sprar(100019,3)  at gml_Object_obj_EBase_StepNormalEvent_1 (line 8) -         sprite_index = sprar[spcounter];

Can you look into this for me ?

Comment: Looks like your `spcounter` has counted too many times and went out of the boundaries of the array. (You defined only as far as `sprar[]` allowed you to). I can see you've wanted to put everything in one state, though I would've seperated them into different states, but try toying around for a bit and see if it works out.

Comment: (On a sidenote, please only post answers if you've found the solution, and try to use comments or edit your question instead, you can always comment on your own questions regardless of reputation)

Comment: By separating into different states you mean sprite states?Maybe you can show me in code ?

Comment: I assume the `sprar[]` are your different sprites. usually, I'll prefer to make an animation of the spite if it only needs to look around (up/down) so you don't have to play around with too much timers to change sprites. animations can be done in the same window of the sprite. I'll try to update my answer later in case it's not clear.

Comment: That would be easier,the thing is changing sprite is one thing.The reason i do this is because i want to add enemy vision cone later.Everytime the sprite changes direction,the vision cone will also point to that direction,2 seconds later it will change to another.Maybe you can suggest another way to do this ?